# API Connect max request size

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

Does anyone know how to set the max request size on API Connect (IBM Cloud)? I'm trying to call an operation of my api and I'm getting a 413 error.

This is the response that I'm getting:

> 413 Request Entity Too Large
>
> ## 413 Request Entity Too
>   Large
>
> ---
>
> nginx

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may be hitting some limits in the API call chain. I suggest you open a support ticket with IBM Cloud in order to better investigate where the request is getting rejected.

Comment: Apparently I am. This is the support team answer:
"Looks like the limit is 1MB. If you are hitting some type of 'monthly' plan limit, you would have to change your plan."

Answer (score 0):

this is IBM Datapower documentation regarding JSON Parser limits: [JSON Parser limits](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/json_parserlimits.html)

The workaround is: Login Datapower WebGUI > changed to the APIM domain > XML Manager > "webapi" & "webapi-internal"

There, in main tab and XML parser tab, you can configure the JSON parser limits (use with caution, as large payloads could create an overhead in processing requests)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alvaro! I'm not using IBM Datapower. I just have an essential plan for IBM Cloud.